# Saving an audio MediaStream into a file

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I am receiving audio in a browser from WebRTC as a MediaStream. I need to convert it to an audio file, preferably an ogg. Ideally, the audio file will be uploaded to the server, but downloading it to the client as a file is the second best option.

I've learned how to upload audio in blobs, so if there is a way to save it to a Blob first, that should be good enough.

Comment: So you know how to record a MediaStream into a Blob and want to find a way to save it to a Blob? There is a catch-22 somewhere in there.

Comment: I don't know how to convert a MediaStream into a Blob. I know how to get a bunch of blobs from MediaRecorder by listening to `dataavailable` event, but this current scenario does't have a MediaRecorder.

Comment: So you want to concatenate all your Blobs into a single one. I'm surprised that wherever you learned how to record the chunks from the MediaRecorder they didn't go to that step. So in your `dataavailable` event you store every chunk in a conventional Array, let's call it `chunks` for this comment. Then, in the `onstop` event of your MediaRecorder (because you don't want to miss the last dataavailable), you simply do `const finalBlob = new Blob(chunks)`. That's it.

Comment: I know how to concatenate all my Blobs into a single one, but that requires obtaining the Blobs in the first place. I think my reference to MediaRecorder in the original question must be confusing, so I removed it as irrelevant. I no longer have a MediaRecorder, because I am not recording anything right now, just obtaining an audio stream from a peer via WebRTC. I don't have `dataavailable` from WebRTC, to the best of my knowlege.

Comment: But using a MediaRecorder is the way to go.  This is what is confusing in your question. You already have the solution to the question in your hands.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot convert a stream directly on the fly into a File or Blob, as a MediaStream is an unlimited data source with no fixed start and end, even if you "just" stream a file from the other side of your connection. A Blob/File on the other hand has a fixed start and end. For conversion, you need to define a start and end *somewhere*.

Depending on your needs, there are countless options on how to actually set start and end boundaries, but it really depends on your needs which one to use (e.g. button press, onended event of the stream tracks, event from server, ...).

As @Kaiido pointed out, you can use MediaRecorder to convert parts of a MediaStream to Blob. Blobs can then be converted to File:

```
let recordedData = [];
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( yourIncomingStream, {mimeType: "audio/ogg"});
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    /* add the data to the recordedDataArray */
    recordedData.push(event.data)
}

/* this defines the start point - call when you want to start your audio to blob conversion */
function start() {
    mediaRecorder.start();
}

/* this defines the end of your file, whenever called, a new file is 
created from the recorded data */
function createFileFormCurrentRecordedData() {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedData , {type: "audio/ogg"});
    const file = new File( [ blob ], "yourfilename.ogg", { type: "audio/ogg"} );
    /* then upload oder directly download your file / blob depending on your needs */
}

/* stop the recording */
function stop() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
}

/* if you don't need multiple recordings, you can listen to onstop */
mediaRecorder.onstop = createFileFormCurrentRecordedData;
```